# Matlab set property from class method

Tags: matlab, function, class, methods, properties

I'm trying to access a class property from within a method function. When I modify the property from the constructor, the setter is called and the property is changed. But when I modify the property from another method, the property reverts to the previous value, when the function is terminated, even though the setter is called again.

What is wrong with my code, please help me!
Thanks

The code is below:

```
 classdef random
    properties
        x
    end

    methods
        function obj=random(obj)
            obj.x = 2
            obj.foo(1)
            obj %output x:2, but it should be 1!
        end
        function foo(obj,A)           
            obj.x = A;
            obj %output x:1
        end
        function obj = set.x(obj,newVal)
            obj.x = newVal;
        end
    end
 end
```

Comment: Could you possibly post the code where you use the class so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I simply call the constructor. Then, if I display the value of 'a', it is incorrect.
>>a = random;
>>a
a = 
  random with properties:
    x: 2
>>a.foo(1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody correct me if I am wrong, but I assume the obj in foo is passed by value. So it does get updated within that function space but not returned. So what works is to have it return the object and catch that in the constructor. Try:

```
classdef random
  properties
      x
  end

  methods
      function obj=random(obj)
          obj.x = 2;
          obj = obj.func1(4);
          disp(obj.x);
      end
      function [obj] = func1(obj,A)           
          obj.x = A;
          disp(obj.x);
      end
      function obj = set.x(obj,newVal)
          obj.x = newVal;
      end
  end
 end
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped. I was thinking about something similar in my mind, but couldn't resolve the problem.

Comment: I remember it well because it took me hours myself to figure that out when I ran into that problem.

Comment: Another error I ran into was that the classdef name contained underscore. In that case, when the constructor tried to call the other method, an error was shown, that the function is not found.

I was struggling with that the WHOLE day!